# Show that $\iiint_R \frac{dV}{r^2} = \iint_{S=\partial R}\frac{\vec{r}}{r^2}dS$

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

> Show that
>   $$\iiint_R \frac{dV}{r^2} = \iint_{S=\partial R}\frac{\vec{r}}{r^2}dS$$
>   for $r=\|\vec{r}\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem).

You just need to prove that $\frac{1}{r^2} = div\ \frac{r}{r^2}$ and you're done. Computing the derivatives of the divergence operator :
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - x\left(2x \right)}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2} = \frac{r^2 -2x^2}{r^4}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\ \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - y\left(2y \right)}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2} = \frac{r^2 -2y^2}{r^4}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\ \frac{z}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - z\left(2z \right)}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2} = \frac{r^2 -2z^2}{r^4}\\
$$
And then summing them :
$$
\nabla \cdot (r/r^2) = \frac{3r^2 - 2x^2 - 2y^2 - 2z^2}{r^4} =\frac{3r^2 - 2r^2}{r^4} = \frac{1}{r^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{{1 \over r^{2}}} & = \pars{{\vec{r} \over r}}\cdot
\pars{{1 \over r^{2}}\,{\vec{r}  \over r}} =
\pars{\nabla r}\cdot\nabla\pars{-\,{1 \over r}} =
-\nabla\cdot\bracks{r\,\nabla\pars{1 \over r}} +
r\,\nabla\cdot\nabla\pars{1 \over r}
\\[3mm] & =
-\nabla\cdot\bracks{r\pars{-\,{1 \over r^{2}}\,{\vec{r} \over r}}} + r\,\nabla^{2}\pars{1 \over r} =
\nabla\cdot\pars{\vec{r} \over r^{2}} + r\bracks{-4\pi\,\delta\pars{\vec{r}}} =
\color{#f00}{\nabla\cdot\pars{\vec{r} \over r^{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Use the Divergence Theorem. 
Edit: Wait, which surface integral is this supposed to be? I know different notation.